# ZF - dynamically change default controller

Tags: zend-framework, front-controller

I need to load different controller as the default one in case request comes from mobile device. I was trying to get front controller instance in plugin and set default there based on device detection but it doesn't work.

Is there any way of dynamic change to FC settings?

EDIT:

plugin is registered and working but rest of the code is not

```
 public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
 {
   $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
   $front->setDefaultControllerName('test');
 }
```

Comment: A plugin can do it. What does not work? Can you post your code?

Comment: Why do you need to set a "default" controller to route instead of the actual controller that will be used?